# Acclamation vs. acclaim as nouns: When to use one or the other?

Tags: single-word-requests, grammar, descriptive-grammar

Back when life was simpler, the words “acclamation” and “acclaim” behaved within precise heterogeneous bounds. The first acted publicly as a noun and the second as a verb. I was naive, oblivious to “acclaim’s” notoriously promiscuous life. The bliss continued until one day I hovered over a gawky line in Wikipedia.

> [“It brought acclaim for many Aboriginal artists.”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jimmy_Chi)

Reputable dictionary entries about “acclaim,” assign a slot at the bottom of the page to warn you that, indeed, the word may also crossdress as a noun. But my primitive non-Chomskian logic found it hard to agree. How do you bring “acclaim” and not “acclamation” to Aboriginal artists? I felt the word “acclaim” was too verb-like. So, I kept rewriting the line in my mind to say, “brought acclamation.” But, this combination yielded surprisingly few results in Google.

I had to switch to “praise,” one of “acclaim’s” relative words, to make sense. The grammar behind “brought praise” is native to the modern religious language of revivalism ([Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=acclaim%2Cacclamation&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cacclaim%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cacclamation%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cacclaim%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cacclamation%3B%2Cc0)). Though to me it lacked elegance when replaced with “acclaim,” I had to admit that the phrase was grammatically sound. The sources I consulted, however, offered limited user instructions. So, I still wonder.

> If as nouns they may behave synonymously, **when should we prefer to use “acclaim” over “acclamation”**?

I- Questions with some similarities:

1- [Kudos?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/124618/karma-kudos/125352?r=SearchResults&s=2%7C43.0022#125352)

2- [Notoriety](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/387220/non-pejorative-synonym-of-notoriety/387237#387237)

II- Outside attempts to address the issue:

1- [Differences between acclaim and acclamation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/387220/non-pejorative-synonym-of-notoriety/387237#387237)

2- [Acclaim and credit](https://thesaurus.plus/related/acclaim/credit)

Comment: To me, _acclamation_ suggests enthusiastic praise from a group of people present at the scene, whereas _acclaim_ is praise from people in general, the media etc.

Comment: So, there is a difference in intensity between these two words?

Comment: No, I meant that there is a difference in context. A victorious football team parading the streets receives _acclamation_, the Aboriginal artists in your Wikipedia quote received _acclaim_.

Comment: PS - Looking at the Wikipedia article, I see it refers to singers and not visual artists as I had supposed, but the same applies; presumably their work was praised by critics, their recordings sold well etc.

Comment: Don’t take Wikipedia seriously.  Any fool can write or edit articles — even me.

Comment: Does your consternation at "acclaim" being both a noun and a verb not extend to "praise"? Or, for that matter, "claim"?

Answer (score 2):

> > ACCLAMATION - *noun* 1 : a loud eager expression of approval, praise, or assent
> >      2 : an overwhelming affirmative vote by cheers, shouts, or
> >     applause rather than by ballot <sup>[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/acclamation?utm_campaign=sd&utm_medium=serp&utm_source=jsonld)</sup>

### Definitions of acclamation:

> - An acclamation, in its most common sense, is a form of election that does not use a ballot. "Acclamation" can also signify
>     a kind of ritual greeting and expression of approval in certain social
>     contexts in ancient Rome. <sup>[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acclamation)</sup>
>
>   - An acclamation was formerly one of the methods of papal election. [<sup>Wikipedia</sup>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acclamation_(in_Papal_elections))
> - A shout of approbation, favor, or assent; eager expression of approval; loud applause; The process of electing a person to a post in
>     the absence of other nominees; : A representation, in sculpture or on
>     medals, of people expressing joy; Without opposition in an election. <sup>[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/acclamation)</sup>
> - Acclamatory - Pertaining to, or expressing approval by, acclamation. <sup>[Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/acclamatory)</sup>
>
> ACCLAIM (*n* & *v*.)
>   - transitive verb 1 : applaud, praise, 2 : to declare by acclamation
>   - intransitive verb : to shout praise or applause
>   - noun 1 : the act of acclaiming, 2 : praise, applause.  eg. The book received great acclaim. <sup>!source not verified</sup>
>
> To answer your question (what is the difference & when do we use them) I'd say *acclaim* is far more
>   commonly used than *acclamation.*   But if you must use acclamation, to
>   me it sounds better in the passive tense, eg:  The acclamation
>   received by the author was overwhelming vs. The author received
>   overwhelming acclaim.

From user @Toffler on [italki.](https://www.italki.com/question/51826)

-All edits and formatting changes are my own.

--NOTE-- I know this work is not my own, but I share all opinions disclosed here and felt it unnecessary to repost.

Comment: The italki reference is actually to a Merriam-Webster source, hence the listing of noun subsense (a) (= acclamation, the act, a count usage) before the far less uncommon (b), non-count.

Answer (score 0):

Acclaim is a less specific word. Anyone who is generally praised is receiving acclaim.

To receive acclamation is to be praised/cheered on by a group physically present. It brings to mind a parade or a Roman triumph.